# Tried this:SQL syntax error - can not insert multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

Can not find the problem in this MySQL query. Can't insert rows. Have checked the script many times but can not find out what's wrong.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  'hashtag1,('hashtag1','751','1','2015-11-20 11:37:48','1448019468'), hashtag2,('hashtag2','751','1' at line 2

My script:

```
    $hashtags = array();

    preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $text, $matches);

    if(!empty($matches[0]) ){

    foreach( $matches[0] as $hashtag ){

    $hashtag = strtolower(str_replace('#', '', $hashtag));

    array_push($hashtags, "('$hashtag','$publi','1','".TM1."','".TM2."')");
    }

    $hashtags = array_unique($hashtags);

    $result = mysqli_query($dcon1,'INSERT INTO w_hashtags(htag,publicat,numbr,tm1,tm2) 
VALUES ('.implode(',', $hashtags).') 
    ON duplicate KEY UPDATE numbr=numbr+1, tm1='.TM1.', tm2='.TM2.'') or die(mysqli_error($dcon1));
```

Comment: `echo` the query and you will get the errors.

Comment: give this a whirl `('.implode(',', '".$hashtags."').')`

Comment: Tried this: `$result = mysqli_query($dcon1,"INSERT INTO w_hashtags(htag,publicat,numbr,tm1,tm2) 
VALUES ('.implode(',', '".$hashtags."').') 
    ON duplicate KEY UPDATE numbr=numbr+1, tm1='".TM1."', tm2='".TM2."'") or die(mysqli_error($dcon1));` but the same error + array to string conversation error

Answer (score 1):

At last!

```
$result = mysqli_query($dcon1,"INSERT INTO w_hashtags(htag,publicat,numbr,tm1,tm2) 
VALUES ".implode(',', $hashtags)." 
    ON duplicate KEY UPDATE numbr=numbr+1, tm1='".TM1."', tm2='".TM2."'") or die(mysqli_error($dcon1));
```